# Cannot adjust right margin on table cell using jQuery :last

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

This is a strange one. I'm trying to replicate `:last-child` for older versions of IE that don't support the CSS pseudo class.

If you look at the following code, the background color change works, but the margin does not. A div inside the cell (`.inner`) currently has a margin of 3px, but the margin override isn't happening. I know jQuery can traverse to the div because the background colour change works. This is a problem with IE6 and IE7 only. Anyone have a suggestion? Much appreciated.

```
$J('table tbody tr td .inner:last').css({ 'margin-right':'0px', 'background':'red' });
```

Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

:last-child is the CSS3 selector, and I think you want to apply it to the td, not the .inner div to adjust the margin of the .inner div in the last cell of each row:

> $('table tbody tr td:last-child .inner')...

Comment: `:last-child` is a CSS3 selector.

Comment: Thanks, BoltClock...it was first-child they added in CSS2...I guess CSS4 will have a :penultimate-child selector?

Comment: you already have :nth-child() and :nth-last-child() selectors :D